# Change completion key in TextMate?

Tags: textmate

Is it possible to change the completion key (escape) to command for instance? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the same question asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144974/textmate-remap-escape-for-word-completion):

To remap the <kbd>esc</kbd> key you have to copy

`/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/KeyBindings.dict`

to

`~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/KeyBindings.dict`

and then edit it, preferably using TextMate :) as Property List Editor messes up the codes.

Look for nextCompletion and previousCompletion and replace their values with whatever suits your needs best.

For example, you could replace <kbd>\033</kbd> (code for <kbd>esc</kbd>) to <kbd>->|tab</kbd>.

Comment: both \t and ->| can be esoteric to individuals. Could you change `->|` to `->| tab`?

Comment: @VxJasonxV - no problem. Done.